# Variables in multiple instances of the same script are shared/overridden for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a small neural network evolutionary learning project. When I try to randomly mutate the weights and biases on multiple instances of my NeuralNetwork script, the scripts seem to affect each other for no apparent reason.

The two main scripts are the GameManager script which manages the learning process and many instances of the NeuralNetwork script which each have their own weights and biases.

The problem is that when a new generation is spawned and each NeuralNetwork script gets the same new weights and biases, which they later mutate randomly and uniquely using Mutate() function in the NeuralNetwork script, they all end up with the same weights and biases. I have checked that the Mutate() function works correctly and changes weights and biases independently for each NeuralNetwork instance, however they all get overridden by the "last" script instance to mutate.

I have tried to randomly delay the Mutate() function in each instance of NeuralNetwork, have tried not to instantiate the NeuralNetork script through a prefab, have tried to call Mutate() function from both the GameManager directly and the NeuralNetwork script using a "proxy" boolean. I have also tried to move the Mutate() function to the GameManager. I even tried turning off the GameManager on runtime right before the mutation. Nothing seems to help.

This is the function used to spawn NeuralNetwork at the start of runtime.

```
    void SpawnNeuralNetworks() {
    for (int i = 0; i < creaturesPerGeneration; i++) {
        neuralNetworkGameObjects[i] = Instantiate(new GameObject(), transform);
        neuralNetworkGameObjects[i].name = "NeuralNetwork" + i;
        neuralNetworkScripts[i] = neuralNetworkGameObjects[i].AddComponent<NeuralNetwork>() ;
        neuralNetworkScripts[i].layers = layers;
        neuralNetworkScripts[i].mutationChanceMultiplier = mutationChanceMultiplier;
        neuralNetworkScripts[i].mutationRateMultiplier = mutationRateMultiplier;
    }
}
```

This is the function used to spawn a new generation of creatures(NeuralNetorks are not destroyed).

```
void SpawnNextGeneration() {
    currentGeneration += 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < creaturesPerGeneration; i++) {
        Destroy(creatures[i]);
    }

    CalculateAverageWeightsandBiases();
    fitness = new float[creaturesPerGeneration];
    creatures = new GameObject[creaturesPerGeneration];

    for (int i = 0; i < creaturesPerGeneration; i++) {
        creatures[i] =  Instantiate(creaturePrefab);
        creatures[i].name = "Creature" + i;
        creatures[i].GetComponent<CreatureController>().neuralNetworkID = 
  i;

        neuralNetworkScripts[i].weights = bestWeights;
        neuralNetworkScripts[i].biases = bestBiases;
        neuralNetworkScripts[i].mutate = true;
    }
}
```

Example of the Mutation function. This function is in the NeuralNetwork script.

```
 private void Mutate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.Length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < weights[i].Length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < weights[i][j].Length; k++) {
                if (Random.Range(0f, 100f) <= 100f * 
mutationChanceMultiplier) {
                    weights[i][j][k] *= (1 + Random.Range(-1 / 6f, 
0.2f)*mutationRateMultiplier);
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
void FixedUpdate(){
testWeight = weights[1][1][1];
FeedForward();
}
```

I would expect that expect that the value of `testWeight` for each instance of Neural network would correspond to the value printed by the `print("HasMutated" + " " + weights[1][1][1])` from the `Mutate()` function of corresponding network. However, the `testWeight` for Each instance corresponds to the last value printed to the console (the "last" network to mutate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at this line in the method SpawnNextGeneration():
neuralNetworkScripts[i].weights = bestWeights;

This line makes every instance of NeuralNetwork to reference GameManager.bestWeights
therefore every instance will show the same result.

Comment: Yes, but these weights are then mutated separately in each instance of NeuralNetwork, so I don't think that should cause a problem. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @GordeiPribõtkin If `bestWeigts` is an array, list, or other reference object, then the assignment there is only a reference assignment. Any changes to the data (eg. `weights[0].weight += 1`) would be changed for all the networks, because they all reference the same object. If you want them to all have their own *copy* then you need to *clone* the best weights.

Comment: In your case I think you could get away with keeping two arrays in your NeuralNetwork class. For example bestWeights and localWeights.
Then changing the line where you assign weights in the method Mutate() to: 
localWeights[i][j][k] = bestWeights[i][j][k] * (1 + Random.Range(-1 / 6f, 
0.2f)*mutationRateMultiplier);

Comment: I did exactly what @AntonHabén suggested and it solved the issue. Thank you to everyone for the help!